# document.querySelector('.create-option:first-child').click() does not work

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why the following code does not work:

```
document.querySelector('.create-option:first-child').click()
```

I'm trying to get the first element with class name "create-option" and click on it.

Comment: _I'm trying to get the first element with class name "create-option"_ ... this is not what `:first-child` does.

Comment: You'll need to show us the HTML that you're trying to select, otherwise we can't really tell you much about why it's not working. In the meanwhile, does it work if you use the same selector in CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `:first-child`, it will select the first element with that class.

```js
// just for the demo ...
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('create-option'), function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(d) {
    alert(d.target.innerHTML);
  })
});


document.querySelector('.create-option').click();
```

```html
<div class="create-option">
a
</div>
<div class="create-option">
b
</div>
<div class="create-option">
c
</div>
<div class="create-option">
d
</div>
<div class="create-option">
e
</div>
<div class="create-option">
f
</div>
<div class="create-option">
g
</div>
<div class="create-option">
h
</div>
<div class="create-option">
i
</div>
<div class="create-option">
j
</div>
<div class="create-option">
k
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.create-option')` is a jQuery Object? I'm I missing something here?

Comment: Why should it be a jQuery object? @zer00ne

Comment: `.click()` is a jQuery method?

Comment: Yes it is too, but it's also a method in plain js @zer00ne

Comment: Oh, I thought it was `onclick` for JS, my bad.

Comment: No, with `onclick` you would listen for the click event. But you can issue the click with `click();` - I think it's the same as with jQuery @zer00ne

Comment: Found it, [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click), thanks @baao

Answer (score 0):

`.create-option:first-child` gets the first child of the first element that is a member of that class.

To get the first element that is a member of that class, omit `:first-child`.